# Python Object Comparison without defining __cmp__ for the class

Tags: python, oop, cmp

Suppose I create a class in python, but I don't define a `__cmp__` method for my class. Now I create two instances of that class and compare them. What cmp method does Python use? I ran the code and it returns false when comparing for equality. Does Python compare memory addresses?

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s

    def __str__(self):
        return self.s

x1 = A("jim")
x2 = A("jim")
print x1 == x2
```

Shell says:

```
False
```

Comment: The documentation is quite clear on the `__le__`, `__lt__`, etc. methods.  What are you asking?  Reference http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lambda x,y: id(x)==id(y)` if memory serves.

Comment: I was looking around for something like that through the Python man pages, but couldn't find it. Where did you find that?

Comment: @BlackSheep, don't remember well, but I think I found it while reading the source code.

Comment: No.  The Rich Comparisons are used.  http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__

Comment: S. Lott has found the source: "If no `__cmp__()`, `__eq__()` or `__ne__()` operation is defined, class instances are compared by object identity ('address')."